# compare two 2D-datasets

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I have measured 7 analytes (chemicals found in blood) from a patient, before and after treatment with some drug. These analytes' levels in blood are affected (increased) by drug treatment. The blood sample has been analyzed 12 times.

I therefore have a vector of 7 elements, each element being a set of 12 values (measurements of blood levels for the respective analyte). The 12 values are interchangeable (they are repeated measurements of the same same blood samples, for a given analyte); the 7 analytes are not (they are distinct chemicals whose levels in blood are measured).

I am interested in comparing the before and after responses of this patient. If I were only interested in 1 analyte (and measured it 12 times as before), this would be a unpaired t-test of two sets of data, 12-values before vs. 12 values after.

If I only took one measurement instead of 12, and measured all 7 analytes, this would be a paired t-test of two sets of data, 7D-vector before vs. 7D-vector after.

What test would be appropriate for the general 7x12 case?